# Script file that executes other scripts

Tags: shell, exec

How do you make a script file that executes other scripts line by line? I have multiple scripts that need to be executed in the correct order to work properly

Comment: is it exec filename.sh? Im not sure if it will go in order

Comment: As in Script A completes then you want to run Script B?

Comment: yes thats what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can have scripts execute in order by chaining the command with `&&`

`&&` makes sure the first command has completed before moving onto the other sin the chains. As opposed to `&` which will execute them all even if the prior ones fail.

- first.sh echoes I am First
- second.sh echoes I am Second

Command

```
sh first.sh && sh second.sh
```

Output

```
I am First
I am Second
```

You can tie this into a cron job if you wish to have it execute at certains times etc.

Comment: it is also possible to use ``;`` like this ``sh first.sh; sh second.sh``. The difference between ``&&`` and ``;`` is that ``&&`` proceeds only if previous command exited successfully without any errors and ``;`` will keep going even if your scripts fail.